# Efficiently scanning memory of a process

Tags: c#, memory, editing

Recently I've put together a C# class that can read and write bytes in another processes memory using API calls etc. as I'm sure you've all seen before.

My question however relates to how I can efficiently scan the memory of another process?  I know the basic method of testing each group of 4 bytes until you reach Int32.MaxValue, but I've found it is (as you may imagine) incredibly time and resource consuming.

From what I've read, there is a way to determine the allocated addresses of a process by doing a "HeapWalk".  Can anyone provide me with some code examples and/or information about this and what would be the best way of going about it?

Comment: What exactly are you scanning for? Seems like you should be message passing between processes rather than intruding into their memory.

Comment: Just an integer?  Is it important..?

Comment: I'd take a look at this application, it's open source and does exactly what you want. http://cheatengine.org/

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at the source code.  I'm trying to implement it in C#?

Comment: Vote to close as overly broad: if the question is about "find byte pattern in byte array/stream (also known search for substring)" - plenty of literature to do it faster. Question also could be about  "how to walk structure of process' heap" OR "how to quickly read large amount of data from other process" OR how do I deal with checking full address space of X64 process" OR "how to find allocate regions of a process"... Consider clarifying/aking separate questions...

Comment: There is no out of the hat trick there, but there might be a better logic to do what you are trying to do, provide more details of what exactly you want to achieve in the bigger vision.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is the list of *memory regions*, which is basically a list of pair of memory address / region size.

What you must do is :

- get a handle to the target process using it's process ID (`PID`) using [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- call the [`VirtualQueryEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function until you reach the end of the memory space (i.e. while the result of the method is greater than 0)
- close the process handle you opened

Start `VirtualQueryEx` with `lpAddress` as `0x0`. This will return a `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` structure that contains both `BaseAddress` and `RegionSize` properties (this represents a memory space you can read). Then increment the `lpAdress` parameter with the `RegionSize` value, so next call of `VirtualQueryEx` will return the next region...etc.

Google `OpenProcess`, `CloseHandle`, `VirtualQueryEx` and `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` so you can find the different P/Invoke declarations to use, so you can call those Win32 functions from C#.

Answer (score 0):

May I advise you something to increase your scanning performance.
Most expensive actions are I\O. So if you for example searching for sub-string in memory, read whole memory block before looking inside, instead of reading small chunks of memory.